# Duas requisições Ajax em uma mesma função

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Ao carregar uma página, tenho duas requisições Ajax em sequência que preenchem dois select´s com as opções que vem de tabelas diferentes no banco.

Porém apenas a primeira é executada, a segunda não chega nem a chamar. Já acompanhei com debug, coloquei breakpoint para ver se a segunda requisição entra e não funciona.

As duas são independentes. Segue o código:

```
function Inicio(){
   // Primeira requisição que é executada
   $.get('ctrl/administrativo/modcadcon.ctrl.php',
           {'acao':'todos_atv', 'campo':'mod_status', 'valor':'1'},
           function(ret_mod){

           // Preenche o select com o resultado

           }
   );

   // Segunda requisição não é executada
   $.get('ctrl/administrativo/procadcon.ctrl.php',
           {'acao':'consultar', 'campo':'pro_status', 'valor':'1'},
           function(ret_pro){

           // Não chega aqui...!
           }
   );
}
```

[RESOLVIDO]

Havia um erro no script PHP que recebia a segunda requisição...
Agora as duas funcionam.

Comment: Já colocou um console.log no segundo para ver se há ação?

Comment: Observe também se ocorreu algum erro de javascript na execução da página, pois quando isso acontece, o restante do código que existe depois do erro não roda.

Comment: @sam e @Marcell Alves - a hora que chega na linha do segundo `$.get...`, seguindo com o debug, ele não executa. Deve ter algo errado aqui. O arquivo php existe... tá muito estranho isso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tenta assim :

```
function Inicio(){
   // Primeira requisição que é executada
   $.get('ctrl/administrativo/modcadcon.ctrl.php',{'acao':'todos_atv', 'campo':'mod_status', 'valor':'1'})
         .done(function( data ) {
            console.log('Preenche o select com : ' + data)
            $.get('ctrl/administrativo/procadcon.ctrl.php',{'acao':'consultar', 'campo':'pro_status', 'valor':'1'})
               .done(function( data2 ) {
                  console.log('Preenche o select com : ' + data2)
               });
         });
  }
```

Comment: Essa solução é válida, porém demorei para perceber que o erro estava no script PHP. Muito obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Mesmo assim acho mais seguro de esperar um requisito finalizar antes de fazer o segundo !